# why qwtplot3d don't work in QT5.7.0 ? But it works well in QT5.5.0

Tags: qt

QwtPlot3d (0.3.1) works well in QT5.5.0. Thus, it don't work in QT5.7.0, and it compiles right, may makes .exe file. But it displays black screen when run .exe in "examples directory". why?

Comment: What video card do you have? What version of Qt (origin of the binaries) are you using? This might be a misconfiguration of Qt leading to OpenGL not displaying.

Comment: please post a sample code and a screenshot

Comment: http://qwtplot3d.sourceforge.net/web/navigation/download_frame.html

Comment: [link](https://github.com/sintegrial/qwtplot3d)

Comment: I compile an example "autoswitch" of qwtplot3d, then copy autoswitch.exe to directory ("..\5.5\msvc2013\bin"), it works well.  But when I copy autoswitch.exe to directory ("..\5.7\msvc2013\bin"), it occur black screen when I run it. OpenGL configuration problems?

Comment: If I use "windeployqt" in the directory of "QT5.5/msvc2013/bin", the example of "autoswitch.exe"  works well, but if I use "windeployqt" in the directory of "QT5.7/msvc2013/bin" , it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Qt Creator 4.0.2 Qt 5.7.0 MSVC2013,32Bit]

Qt Creator 4.0.2  Qt 5.7.0 MSVC2013,32Bit